# When to set the itemSize in UICollectionViewFlowLayout when itemSize changes for different orientations?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In a UICollectionView with a flow layout, I want to use itemSize rather than itemSizeForCellAtIndexPath because the size of the cells is constant for each orientation. However, the size of the cells depends on the size of the view of the view controller, which is not determined until runtime.

When is the right time to set itemSize?

Comment: Are you using autolayout?

Answer (score 0):

Well as I have no idea if you are using `AutoLayout` or not I am going to suggest you for both.

```
if (using AutoLayout)
    set it inside: -(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
else
    set it inside: - (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
```